# How to fix this error: "No irq handler for vector"

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I have done `sudo do-release-upgrade` from 21.10 to 22.04 Ubuntu and suddenly I get this error when I start my computer:

```
[    0.004902] __common_interrupt:1.55 No irq handler for vector
/dev/sda2: clean, 3697434/45760512 files, 55603510/183012096 blocks
```

My computer starts normally after that.

What does it mean? Is this a serious error or can I leave it as is?

Comment: I have some problem on my ubuntu 22.04 LTS after new installation. That message doesn't appear on my ubuntu 20 version before.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you explain more?

Comment: In general, it is perfectly normal for kernel messages and "errors" to show at boot; they are useful if you are doing kernel development and need them for debugging. If you aren't, and your system works fine, you are safe to ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about:

1. Possible causes
2. Severity / Need for fixing

I first noticed a similar message in my recently installed Bodhi Linux (an Ubuntu derivative), and I didn't notice anything wrong with OS functioning. As per this, for item 2 above I would say you shouldn't be concerned.
It might have happened to me in other systems, and I simply didn't notice it.

In [this long thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256227) it is reported that updating the BIOS made the message disappear, e.g. [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1947839#p1947839).
Also, disabling `IOMMU` in the BIOS helped some, e.g. [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1937876#p1937876) (but for others this didn't work).

As for item 1, the error seems to arise when a multiple CPU cores are initialized ([ref](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/2/19/516)), but it's possibly safe to ignore ([ref](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1908650#p1908650)).

I suggest you try disabling `IOMMU` in the BIOS if possible, and post feedback.
Also, please post:

1. The complete model of your PC, and motherboard.
2. Output of `uname -a`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a laptop, it's the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> light that comes on called a sensor driver. Just ignore the error as your system works after boot.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal analysis so far this is caused by interchange of SecureBoot with ACPI or signature of the Linux or kernel modules in general. But is very hard to find something about this on the net.

In my case the error appeared on my OpenSuse Leap 15.2 for `eth0` and also Wifi (chipset RTL8821).

```
$ uname -a
Linux linux-6a0h 5.3.18-lp152.106-preempt #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 22 08:38:17 UTC 2021 (52078fe) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update 06.05.2023

Upgrading a Linux distro when using KDE Wallet causes NetworkManager service  to disconnect from KDE Wallet

-> https://forums.opensuse.org/t/networkmanager-lost-connection-to-kdewallet/139606

a (not nice) workaround for enabling Wifi again is here -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420497/how-do-i-stop-kwallet-from-asking-my-password-to-let-the-system-connect-to-wifi/478227#478227

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing "XHCI Mode" in BIOS: from "Windows 10" to "Windows 7"