# No irq handler for vector

Tags: boot

I recently started using Ubuntu and after some time using it, an error message started to appear "__common_interrupt: 1.192 no irq handler for vector". everyone is saying that there's no need to pay attention to the error but my pc is not booting up, there's also another message above it 5 times "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)" but from what I know that shouldn't be the reason why it's not booting up but it might be relevant. The pc was just fine yesterday. I tried updating grub from bootable USB but that was happening in the usb and idk how to edit the grub in the SSD of the pc. I'm completely clueless rn I'll try any ideas in the worst case I will have to re install Ubuntu.

And sorry for my bad English

Comment: did you change anything at all after it booted the last time, but before the new boot issues?

Comment: No everything was just like the last time except updating drivers and from what I heard it's GPU driver problem so I think that was the issue. Anyway I reinstalled Ubuntu and everything seems to be fine

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405604/how-to-fix-this-error-no-irq-handler-for-vector You can see some potential solutions there.